# Liquibase script to delete or clear all data in the column

Tags: database, liquibase

Is there a way in liquibase to **clear all the data** in the CharSkill column using **liquibase** without depending on the content of the table?

Since I'll be deploying this to multiple users the content may vary but the columns are constant.

*I can use drop column and then add the same column but I would like to know if it's the best way.*

**BEFORE:**

User A's character table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| CharID | CharName | CharSkill |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | Mickey   | Run       |
|      2 | Minnie   | Jump      |
|      3 | Donald   | Kick      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

User B's character table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| CharID | CharName | CharSkill |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | Goofy    | Punch     |
|      2 | Daisy    | Laugh     |
|      3 | Pluto    | Sing      |
|      4 | Stitch   | Crawl     |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

**AFTER:**

User A's character table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| CharID | CharName | CharSkill |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | Mickey   |           |
|      2 | Minnie   |           |
|      3 | Donald   |           |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

User B's character table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| CharID | CharName | CharSkill |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | Goofy    |           |
|      2 | Daisy    |           |
|      3 | Pluto    |           |
|      4 | Stitch   |           |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple [`<update>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html) without a where clause should do that:

```
<changeSet author="loren" id="1">
    <update tableName="character">
        <column name="charskill"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

alternatively just use a `<sql>` tag:

```
<changeSet author="loren" id="1">
    <sql>update character set charskill=null</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Does this also deletes foreign keys? If yes how can you do it without doing that.